# cakephp multiple domains & Configure::write

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Running multiple domains on one install.  In bootstrap I have:

```
   Configure::write('Application.name', 'example1.com');
   Configure::write('Application.name', 'example2.com');
```

What's the best way to define these variables so that I can check my main domain and set them up all at once?

Comment: Found this:
http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/eimermusic/2009/02/18/one-core-one-app-multiple-domains

Comment: Please check my answer. If it's useful, set the answer as accepted or vote it up. Otherwise just write what's missing in the answer or what are the problems you're dealing with now and I'll try to help.

Answer (score 1):

To check your domain in bootstrap.php/core.php file you can just use:

```
switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
    case 'example1.com':
        Configure::write('Application.name', 'Example1');
        Configure::write(...);
        break;
    case 'example2.com':
        ...
        break;
}
```

If you want to organise your configuration in more clear way, you can save your app configuration in separate files, which names are based on the domain name. For example:

```
$filename = 'bootstrap_' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '.php';
require_once($filename);
```

But remember that this domain specific configuration won't work when running CakePHP console. You can find a way to run console apps here:
http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/eimermusic/2009/02/18/one-core-one-app-multiple-domains

Comment: Right, that goes boom in CLI mode.. Also don't use $_SERVER directly, use env().